# Text and font-awesome icon wont change on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the text of a button when clicked and back to normal when clicked again. The button is using a font awesome icon so figured I would try using this.html instead of this.text, but for some reason it is not recognising the HTML I am indicating?

If I change the HTML on the else statement then it will change on click which is what makes me think it is an issue with it not recognizing my HTML.

I know it might be something really stupid but cant seem to figure it out.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).html()=="View code <i class=\"fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs\"></i>")
    {
        $(this).html("Close code <i class=\"fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs\"></i>");
    } else {
        $(this).html("View code <i class=\"fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs\"></i>");
    }
})
});
```

```
      <div class="getcodebuttoncontainer">
         <button
         type="button"
         class="btn-primary"
         id="submitbutton"
         onclick="retrieveData()"
         >View code <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i></button>
      </div>
```

Comment: To let you know .The main problem here is you're trying to compare `.html() ==` that's not right .. you can compare `.text()` instead .. Something like `($(this).text().trim() == "View code")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the only change is the text  ( "View || Close ") so you can simply put that variable text in spans - one with a display: none styling and then on the click - toggle the visibility of each.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
  })
});
```

```css
#submitbutton span:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="getcodebuttoncontainer">
  <button
  type="button"
  class="btn-primary"
  id="submitbutton"
  >
    <span>View</span>
    <span>Close</span>
    code <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-xs"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing - you had two click handlers - on as the onclick in the html and one in the js  - its better code structure (esp with jQuery) to have them all in the JS - so i removed the inline one in my solution.

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback, I have followed your advice and am now calling the function within the same click event.

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggle();
    $("#submitbutton").toggleClass("btn-unpressed btn-pressed");
    retrieveData();
    $('#viewJsSnippet').toggle();
  });
  })